# How to inline a textarea with a label so that the textarea keeps its normal flow and wraps around the label

Tags: html, css, textarea

I've searched for similar questions but none seem to address this specific issue, what I'm trying to do is accomplish something like this:

```
Label -------------------
-------------------------
-------------------------
```

where the "Label" is the actual label and the "-" represents my text area, I've tried everything from floats to inline the elements but I just can't figure this out, is there a way to accomplish this **without** having the label to be absolute therefore hiding the text when the textarea is scrollable?

Comment: Do you have any code that can be looked ?

Comment: You want the label to scroll with the textarea or not, I don't understand?

Comment: @danny I will try to build an example

Comment: @FourCinnamon0 no, the label should stay in the same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know about doing this with a `<textarea>` without involving JS, But you can always use contenteditable

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

[contenteditable]>span {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span contenteditable="false">Label:</span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae rhoncus felis, vel auctor tortor. Nunc porttitor arcu eget luctus feugiat.
</div>
```

There's room for improvements still and require management of course.